# MVC: Can I clear ViewBag from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have an action that sends any error message to the Viewbag. When the page loads, at error message in the Viewbag will be presented as a JS alert.

Is there a way in JavaScript to clear the Viewbag? This way, when I get this error and then click somewhere else to get to another page, and then click the BACK button on my browser, the viewbag doesn't still contain anything (including this error message). Right now if I click back, the error message will still appear. I figure if there's a way to clear the ViewBag with JS, this wouldn't happen.

Comment: You should review your design and not mix server side and client side processes. Maybe make your client side throw the message instead of just trying to hack it.

Comment: @PmanAce He's doing the right thing. Client side code is great for UI validation (instant feedback rather than making a server call), however if you manage to bypass the client side validation (using various techniques) you should still throw a validation error from the server side.

Comment: @Pete That's not true. ViewBag is only available during the lifecycle of the request within which you populated it.

Comment: @Pete One to test for myself I guess as I never came across that one. It would make sense for that to work, but I think I misinterpreted where the lifecycle of the request ends...

Comment: @Adriani6 you are right the server side should still validate, but he shouldn't be using the viewbag and a JS alert in my opinion. His model should include an error object and he could create a bootstrap alert type of thing that is easily dismissible.

Comment: @PmanAce That's right, However `TempData` for example is perfectly valid to transport validation messages. In my opinion ViewBag isn't good for this job either however in my comment I was referring to _You should review your design and not mix server side and client side processes._

Comment: This isn't for validation. The error message I'm referring to is coming back from SQL server after a sproc executes.  I originally had my call as an AJAX call which would have solved my problem, but my requirements have changed and my call has to be a regular form post and if there are any issues with my (extremely complicated) stored procedure, the message has to be shown using a JS alert. So basically, I either use Viewbag to pass the message bag and do an alert on that, or I put the message in a hidden field and when the page loads, do an alert and show this hidden field content.

Comment: I *think* that if I use the latter method, and put the message in a hidden field and then clear this field with the UNLOAD JS event, that might solve the issue, but I really despise using this unload event. Different browsers handle it differently and some browsers might either tend to think of it as some kind of hijack attempt or I have a fear that in the near future, many browsers will deprecate this. Doing any JS work with unload events just feels... (shivers) dirrrrty. Ya know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, a `ViewBag` is completely server side.

The real issue with this is that the back button won't make another request to your server as this is loaded from the browser's cache.

You can get around this by making the XHR calls on page load that retrieve the data (rather than sending the data to the client on the initial get request). Once you've done this you can follow @Adriani6's suggestion of using `TempData`.